# How can i save custom fields in registration from to my database? (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a school related website with django. So i created a custom user model looks like this (Sorry for the foreign field names):

```
class ogrenciler(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ogr_adi = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ogr_soyadi = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sinifi = models.ForeignKey(siniflar, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numara = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    foto = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ogr_adi + " " + self.ogr_soyadi + "ogrencisi"
```

and this is my custom registiration form:

```
class ogrenciKayit(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    numara = forms.CharField(max_length=5, required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'numara', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(ogrenciKayit, self).save(commit=False)
        user.numara = self.cleaned_data['numara']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

I created a signal.py file to whenever a user created also create a "ogrenci"(student). This is my signals.py file:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_ogrenci(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ogrenciler.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_ogrenci(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.ogrenciler.save()
```

Everything works fine but the "numara" field doesn't get saved.

This is my views.py file if you wanna check it:

```
def ogrenciregister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ogrenciKayit(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username= form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Hesap {username} adına oluşturuldu.')
            return redirect('giris')
    else:
        form = ogrenciKayit()
    return render(request, 'kullanicilar/ogrencikayit.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, explain why the field can not be saved.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
```

The `sender` is just the user in the database, It is not the object you returned in your save function. It don not have the field you want

write the creation of related object in your  save function of form .

In this way you can get the value of field

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you're saying but i don't know how to write the code, i found [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/) but im still lost can you help me a little more please

Comment: In your form's save fuction, write the process of ogrenciler creation which you writed in the signal part.  Only in this part ,you can get the value of the  `numara` field